# DRF test if JSON list of objects contains a specific object

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework, pytest

I'm testing an endpoint from Django DRF, which produces a JSON list of objects. I'm trying to check if a specific object is in the returned list. I've tried assertIn and assertContains, but they produce errors.

My endpoint returns list of objects:

```
[
  {
    'id' : 1,
    'name': 'HelpMe'
  },
  {
    'id' : 2,
    'name': 'WhatToDo'
  },
  {
    'id' : 3,
    'name': 'ToSolveThis'
  },
]
```

Test code for the assertIn:

```
    def test_list(self):      
        client = APIClient()

        response = client.get('/api/some_list/', format='json')

        self.assertEqual(
            len(response.data),
            19
        )

        self.assertIn(
            response.data,
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "WhatToDo"
            }
        )
```

assertIn produces `TypeError: unhashable type: 'ReturnList'`

Test code for the assertContains:

```
    def test_list(self):      
        client = APIClient()

        response = client.get('/api/some_list/', format='json')

        self.assertEqual(
            len(response.data),
            19
        )

        self.assertContains(
            response,
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "WhatToDo"
            }
        )
```

assertContain just failed the test.

What is the best approach to test if a specific object exists in the JSON list in response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have inverted the arguments of: `assertIn`, try this:

```
self.assertIn({"id": 2, "name": "WhatToDo"}, response.data)

# Or you can also write:
self.assertTrue({"id": 2, "name": "WhatToDo"} in response.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your examples cover situations when I have a single object in JSON response. but what about a list of objects? Is the only way is to write some extra code to iterate through the list and check if an object exists? On the other way, in DRF documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#checking-the-response-data they give us an example where we can test a single object with simple assertEqual

Comment: I've updated my question with an example of endpoint's response

Comment: @a13xg0 I have update my answer, I think you have inverted the arguments of `assertIn`.

Comment: Oh, (facepalm) you are right! ) Now is better, but now error is about types:

self.assertIn(
AssertionError: {'id': 3, name: 'WhatToDo'}  not found in [OrderedDict([('id', 2), ( ... etc

Comment: @a13xg0 That error means `{'id': 3, name: 'WhatToDo'}` is not contained in `response.data`, to debug try: `print(response.data)` to see what is going on.

Comment: @Alain did you find a good way of testing this? I can pick out an attribute on index 0 and AssertEqual on that, but that seems inelegant/wrong...

Comment: @Tsaari If you have for example a list named `exampleList` whose first element should be equal to `exampleValue`, I would write directly: `self.assertEqual(exampleList[0], exampleValue)`